# Import Gmail Message to Google Sheet as text so it falls into Cells

Tags: google-sheets, gmail

Sorry for the somewhat cryptic title, didn't know quite how to phrase it! Here is my problem:

I am using this code:

```
function getMessagesWithLabel() {
     var destArray = new Array();
      var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Staff').getThreads(0,1);

      for(var n in threads){
            var msg = threads[n].getMessages();
            var destArrayRow = new Array();
            destArrayRow.push('thread has '+threads[n].getMessageCount()+' messages');
              for(var m in msg){
                destArrayRow.push(msg[m].getBody());
               }
      destArray.push(destArrayRow);           
            }
    Logger.log(destArray);
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if(ss.getLastRow()==0){sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('getMessagesWithLabel() RESULTS')};
    sh.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,destArray.length,destArray[0].length).setValues(destArray)
    }
```

to pull in the body of of the first email with the label staff to a google sheet.

This works well, but places the body all in one cell (B2)

Is there a way to "paste" the body of the email into the sheet as text, so that each line of the body text falls into its own cell?

If no way of doing this, I have found that if I enter B2 to edit it, then CTRL+A and CTRL+C, I can then paste to a new range and the contents fall into a cell per line. I can then work with the content of the email body - I need to extract a list of names from it, using formulas to tidy up the text and remove the html code. How can I do this edit copy paste of a cell using google apps script. i have tried all the "copy" and "range" functions and these all just replicate what I have already.

Happy with a solution either way?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, that was too simple! After some googling around parsing gmails etc. the answer was staring me in the face, and it could all be easily done in google sheets. Using **transpose** and **split** with **CHAR(10)** as the delimiter gave me exactly what I wanted. CHAR(10) finds the new lines in the gmail body.

**=transpose(split(Sheet1!B2, CHAR(10), TRUE))**